# Missing translation on German http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization, careers-germany

The German version of the [Stack Overflow Careers FAQ](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq) contains the following three sections that are not translated into German.

### 1.

> What is Stack Overflow Careers?
>
> [image]

### 2.

> Think of ecosystems as bundles of tags. Tags themselves are very narrow in scope, while ecosystems involve a wide range of technologies that are related. Furthermore, Tags are derived mostly from your job listing's *Key Technologies*, where as ecosystems allow you to dictate your needs.
>
> [image]

### 3.

> FAQ For Programmers
>
> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report! I've fixed up the headings but the paragraph will need to wait for our next translation batch to complete. That shouldn't be too far off.